# Snowpipe recreation and possibility of sqs changing

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpipe

When recreating a snowpipe, how likely is it that the pipe's sqs arn changes?

The documentation recommends double checking everything after recreation. It implies that the sqs might change. But I'm interested to hear has anyone noticed such phenomenon?

If the sqs changes, the IaC deployment process becomes complicated.

Comment: There was another similar discussion, putting it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71595636/snowpipe-loading?noredirect=1#comment126551113_71595636

Comment: @Pankaj Thanks, it seems to be unclear in that discussion also. The other person claims that it wouldn't change but I'm not sure about the credibility.