# How can I configure a snowpipe to grab the same filename from an S3 bucket when the file is refreshed and re-uploaded?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a csv file that is maintained by an analyst who manually updates it at irregular intervals and reuploads (by drag and drop) the same file to an S3 bucket. I have Snowpipe set up to ingest files from this S3 bucket, but it won't re-process the same filename even when the contents change. We don't want to rely on the analyst(s) remembering to manually rename the file each time they upload it, so are looking for an automated solution. I have pretty minimal input on how the analysts work with this file, I just need to ingest it for them. The options I'm considering are:

1. Somehow adding a timestamp or unique identifier to the filename on
   upload (not finding a way to do this easily in S3). I've also
   experimented with versioning in the S3 bucket but this doesn't seem
   to have any effect.
2. Somehow forcing the pipe to grab the file again even with the same name. I've read
   elsewhere that setting "Force=true" might do it, but that seems to
   be an invalid option for a pipe COPY INTO statement.

Here is the pipe configuration, I'm not sure if this will be helpful here:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PIPE S3_INGEST_MANUAL_CSV AUTO_INGEST=TRUE AS
    COPY INTO DB.SCHEMA.STAGE_TABLE
    FROM(
    SELECT $1, $2, metadata$filename, metadata$file_row_number
    FROM @DB.SCHEMA.S3STAGE
    )
    FILE_FORMAT=(
    TYPE='csv'
    skip_header=1
    ) ON_ERROR='SKIP_FILE_1%'
    enter code here
```

Comment: Did you find any solution or workaround for your need. Please do share if any ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that updating the same file rather than having a unique filename is really bad practice, you can use the FORCE option to force the reloading of the same file.

If the file hasn't been changed and you run the process with this option you'll  potentially end up with duplicates in your target

Comment: Thanks, I will push back against the idea of updating the same file, although I may not have much influence there. 

When I add the FORCE option to the CREATE PIPE statement I receive the following error:

"SQL compilation error: Invalid copy option 'FORCE' in pipe definition."

Any idea what's going on there?

Comment: Not without seeing your full pipe definition

Comment: Dont think FORCE option is supported in snowpipe - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-pipe.html#usage-notes

Comment: Refer this thread, it has similar discussion i.e. load same file again. Suggestion is to recreate pipe - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71595636/snowpipe-loading?noredirect=1#comment126551113_71595636

Comment: All COPY INTO <table> copy options are supported except for the following in snowpipe:

FILES = ( 'file_name1' [ , 'file_name2', ... ] )

ON_ERROR = ABORT_STATEMENT

SIZE_LIMIT = num

PURGE = TRUE | FALSE (i.e. automatic purging while loading)

FORCE = TRUE | FALSE